# How to retrieve user's Lived places, Trips and Life Events from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Users can add "Lived places", "Trips" and "Life Events" on a Map on the new Timeline.
As you can get user's checkins via Graph API, I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve those locations as well?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook's [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and documentation this is not currently implemented as a GET possibility in the Graph API.

However, with the appropriate access token, you can retrieve certain aspects of a profile that include a Location ID that can be used to find the Location on Facebook, which you can then retrieve the Address, City, State, Coordinates, etc.

So, all around, the answer is no, at this time, you cannot retrieve Map information with Graph API. Hopefully, Facebook will make this available in the future.

**ETA:** I just just reviewed the Facebook OAuth Scope List and did some trial and error with the Graph API Explorer. I discovered the following...

- While there is a permission scope for "user_location_posts" that must be included in the access token in order to get the location posts (i.e. statuses with a "Place" section) to show up in the feed/posts return from the appropriate GET call, there is no way to only retrieve the posts defined as "user_location_posts." In order to retrieve posts at all, you must first have the "read_stream" or "export_stream" permission which returns everything, not just the location posts.
- You're going to need permissions to get the rest of the profile to find the locations on their photos, videos, and any other components that could potentially have a location attached.
- There is a strong possibility that there is a Facebook component called "locations". Currently, it returns the GET error "(#100) Subject must be a part of the whitelist" rather than the typical error of "component does not exist". Therefore, it's possible that it's there and that the public does not have access to it at this time. It's also possible that this is just a bug I found.